# File picking and choosing nothing

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently using the below to pick file, there isn't a bug per-say well it is and it isn't, I can't figure out the user is supposed to cancel a selection and or select nothing, it appears as though you must always choose a file in order to return, the back button doesn't help that just goes backwards up the file tree but not back to the previous activity /fragment.

```
    private val getContentCardFullImage = registerForActivityResult( ActivityResultContracts.GetContent() )  { uri: Uri ->
    if(uri != Uri.EMPTY) {
        val image = requireActivity().findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iViewFullScreenImage)
        image.setImageURI(uri)

        val file = File( uri?.path )
        mydecklist[cCardPosition].c_fullscreenimageuri = mytools.getImageFromMediaStore(requireContext(),file.name)

        Log.e("getContentCardFullImage","URI = "+uri.toString())
    }
}
```

Eventually pressing back results in

```
2021-09-01 10:34:05.738 6936-6936/com.rdesign.cardgame E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.rdesign.cardgame, PID: 6936
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter uri
    at com.rdesign.cardgame.FragmentEdCardsMediaFullscreenImage.getContentCardFullImage$lambda-0(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.rdesign.cardgame.FragmentEdCardsMediaFullscreenImage.$r8$lambda$9zsJXI9tGiAk_-RzMTu4ELCl2cI(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.rdesign.cardgame.FragmentEdCardsMediaFullscreenImage$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.onActivityResult(Unknown Source:4)
    at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$1.onStateChanged(ActivityResultRegistry.java:148)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:265)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:307)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:148)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:134)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3026)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:589)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:300)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:3079)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:262)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:510)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8222)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3818)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: A few times the back button does it. Indeed.

Comment: eventually yes, but that results in back and the crashing.

Comment: Make a nullable check using ?. to make sure URI is not null

Comment: that was the right answer yes, doesn't explain the tree view going back multiple directories before returning however, very bizarre behavior.

Answer (score 0):

using kotlin null safety check

```
private val getContentCardFullImage = registerForActivityResult( ActivityResultContracts.GetContent() )  { uri ->
    uri?.let {
        val image = requireActivity().findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iViewFullScreenImage)
        image.setImageURI(uri)

        val file = File( uri?.path )
        mydecklist[cCardPosition].c_fullscreenimageuri = mytools.getImageFromMediaStore(requireContext(),file.name)

        Log.e("getContentCardFullImage","URI = "+uri.toString())
     }
}
```

by doing so everything inside the block will not be executed until the uri is not null

Comment: Would that not force the user to select something or quit the application ?

Comment: unfortunately it will force the user to choose a file but at least it will avoid the crash when there is not an uri to handle

Answer (score 0):

Seemed better to just check if uri != null, fixed the crash on null at least.

-- However doesn't completely resolve the pressing of back multiple times to return back to the application.

```
// Animated Image
private val getContentCardAnimImage = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent())  { uri: Uri? ->
    if(uri != null) {
        if (uri != Uri.EMPTY) {
            val image = requireActivity().findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iViewAnimImage)
            val contentResolver = requireActivity().contentResolver
            val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(contentResolver, uri)
            val drawable = ImageDecoder.decodeDrawable(source)

            Log.d("EditCards", uri.toString())

            image.setImageDrawable(drawable)

            if (drawable is AnimatedImageDrawable) {
                drawable.start()
                //drawable.repeatCount = 2
            }

            val file = File(uri?.path)
            mydecklist[cCardPosition].c_animimageuri = mytools.getImageFromMediaStore(requireContext(), file.name)
        }
    }
}
```